# Error with Groovy AST: tried to access field ..TupleConstructorASTTransformation.MY_TYPE

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I need someone to help me solve this error.

**Full error:**

> Error with Groovy AST:  tried to access field
>   ..TupleConstructorASTTransformation.MY_TYPE from class
>   ...CanonicalASTTransformation at
>   ...CanonicalASTTransformation.visit(CanonicalASTTransformation.java:66)

Groovy file looks like this:

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF217.jpg)

Comment: Add code here not like image and link

Comment: Not sure where Canonical or TupleConstructor is coming into play in your code.  You may need to provide additional details.  Also, no need for type parameter "<T>" on your JSON class; you don't use it for anything.